# Is it possible to allow non-localhost clients to access a local implementation of an App Engine Servlet?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

The local implementation of the App Engine Servlet (Java) is on the machine `192.168.0.2`.

Is it possible for a web browser on `192.168.0.3` to access `http://192.168.0.2:8888`?

If so, how can it be done?

Thank you in advance guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, you will not be able to access it unless you add the `--host` parameter while starting up the dev server.

So go ahead and add `--host=0.0.0.0` while starting up the Dev Server.

As per the documentation, you need to add `--address=0.0.0.0` while starting up (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#Command_Line_Arguments) but folks are reporting that starting from SDK 1.8.7, you need to replace `--address` with `--host`